# flutter error: Got error Undefined name 'context'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

### Undefined name 'context'

I am getting error on context which is inside catch block.

```
catch (e) {
      // showToast( "$e Location services is Required");
      dismisDialog(context);  // I got error here
    }



Future<void> dismisDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Title'),
          content: Text('This is Demo'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text('Go Back'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: try to add your try catch using BuildContext, Or add extra code

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you will add full code